# Multiple Sql Jobs success email

Tags: sql-server

I have multiple sql jobs running on my sql server. Now I want to send an email notification to my team daily after a group of my sql jobs have succeded. How can i achieve this?

Comment: One way to do this would be to create a new sql job to query the sql job histories you are interested in and then return either success or fail depending on your criteria. Have those success / fail actions linked to sending an email on completion.

Answer (score 0):

We do so using with some imagination and external tools...

First of all you have to decide what means SUCCEED for a job.
If you just need to check job history, take a look to: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/88810/what-is-the-query-to-display-the-failed-sql-jobs

In our case if a job ends well but last 4 hours is not Ok. So on each job we save a log when it started the the step and when it finished or if it finished ok. To do so, on each job step we add a piece of code before and after in order to save if it went Ok or not.

Said so, you just need to create a new job which evaluates your log or the job history and send a mail using [xp_cmdshell](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and some command line tool like [SendMail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/).

The step should look something like:

```
-- Variable Declarations
DECLARE @PreviousDate datetime  
DECLARE @Year VARCHAR(4)   
DECLARE @Month VARCHAR(2)  
DECLARE @MonthPre VARCHAR(2)  
DECLARE @Day VARCHAR(2)  
DECLARE @DayPre VARCHAR(2)  
DECLARE @FinalDate INT  

-- Initialize Variables  
SET @PreviousDate = DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()) -- Last 1 day   
SET @Year = DATEPART(yyyy, @PreviousDate)   
SELECT @MonthPre = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(mm, @PreviousDate))  
SELECT @Month = RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, (@MonthPre + 1000000000)),2)  
SELECT @DayPre = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(dd, @PreviousDate))  
SELECT @Day = RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, (@DayPre + 1000000000)),2)  
SET @FinalDate = CAST(@Year + @Month + @Day AS INT)  

-- Final Logic 

IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1
FROM     msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h  
         INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j  
           ON h.job_id = j.job_id  
         INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps s  
           ON j.job_id = s.job_id 
           AND h.step_id = s.step_id  
WHERE    h.run_status = 0 -- Failure  
         AND h.run_date > @FinalDate  
)
BEGIN
    EXEC xp_cmdshell 'sendEmail.exe -o tls=yes -f sender@gmail.com -t recipient@email.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu sender@gmail.com -xp YourGmailPassword -u subject -m body'
END
```

There you can customize your subject and body as preferred.